# Getting: "java.lang.NullPointerException" but I know object is instantiated in AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, nullpointerexception

I am attempting to pass a string I got in an Asynchronous task class back in to my main activity, but when I pass the string result (which I know isn't null because logging the string right before passing it to the interface outputs what it should), I get a nullPointerException that says I can't pass a null object to the interface method.

Here is the AsyncTask class,

```
public class APICalls extends AsyncTask<String,Void, String> {
    public AsyncResponse delegate;

    protected String doInBackground(String... zipcodes){
        String zipcode = zipcodes[0];
        String apikey = "6562c36e87ba41f6bc887104d1e82eb8";
        String baseURL = "https://congress.api.sunlightfoundation.com";
        String zipCodeAddition = "/legislators/locate?apikey="+apikey + "&zip=" + zipcode;
        String url = baseURL + zipCodeAddition;
        String results = "";
        URL apiurl = null;
        try {
            apiurl = new URL(url);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        HttpsURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        try {
            urlConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) apiurl.openConnection();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
            int data = in.read();
            while(data != -1){
                results += String.valueOf((char) data);
                data = in.read();
            }
            in.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            urlConnection.disconnect();
        }
        return results;
    }
protected void onPostExecute(String result){
        String results = result;
        try {
            delegate.processFinish(results);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The error occurs in the line delegate.processFinish(results);. When I log the results string it is not null. The interface is:

```
public interface AsyncResponse {
    void processFinish(String output) throws IOException;
}
```

Then in the main activity I implement the interface and have the method:

```
public void processFinish(String output) throws IOException {
    Log.v("++++++++", output);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get NPE not because `output` is `null`, but because `delegate` is. You never initialize it.

Comment: How do I initialize delegate? I initially had    
    public AsyncResponse delegate = null;
But that is still null (not surprisingly)

Comment: @user3650330 depends on what `delegate` is. If it's an activity for example and you create your `APICalls` inside it, you can add a new constructor like `new APICalls(this).execute(...)...`, and assign your `delegate` to the passed `Activity` that implements `AsyncResponse`.

Comment: Thank you! I got it working. I needed to add a constructor to the APICalls class that had a delegate from my main activity as a parameter and then assign the delegate in APICalls to the passed in delegate.